# Как записать звук который воспроизводят колонки (звук не с микрофона) в python?

Tags: python, linux, аудио, python-2.x

Как записать звук который воспроизводят колонки (звук не с микрофона) с помощью python? OS Linux 32x

Comment: Это называется audio loopback и варианты реализации скорее всего зависят от дистрибутива, настроек

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/597227/454489

Comment: нашёл pyaudio, но получилось сделать запись только с микрофона((